# Floating Point Exception handling in ARM assembly

Tags: exception, arm

So if I have an exception say inside a subroutine, what happens? Does the function returns NaN (or whatever else appropriate) or it just quits the whole application?

From what I gathered reading ARM documentation, if the exception trap enable  bits are not set then it just writes the appropriate NaNs or infinities back.

Is there a way to pass to the caller the information back through the status register without getting the application quit as soon as there is an exception? I think I am looking for some kind of exception handler, however I am implementing the subroutine in assembly so not sure how to write an exception trap handler.

Comment: Your question does not explicitly state this, but it sounds like you are asking regarding floating-point exceptions, as opposed to interrupts or load/store exceptions and such. Also, you do not mention what processor (and thus architecture version) you are developing for, and whether or not you are writing code for "bare metal" or for running under an operating system. Could you please confirm (and update the question)?

Comment: Thanks! Yes floating point exception is what I am worried about here. I am using VFP v2 for Cortex M4. I am writing the code for running under a OS more of a simulating the hardware in keil.